# What to conclude from parameters of the simple linear regression model about data

Tags: r, math, statistics

I had a dataset for which I needed to provide a linear regression model that represents diameter as a function of length.Data which has length in first column and diameter in second looked like:
0.455,0.365
0.44,0.365

I carried out the required operations on the given dataset in R,and plotted the regression line for the data [image]

I am just confused about what to conclude from the parameters(slope=0.8154, y intercept:-0.019413, correlation coefficient:0.98 ). Can I conclude anything other than line is a good fit. I am new to statistics. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slope 0.8154 informs you that each unit increase for lenght causes increase of diamater in 0.8154*unit. Intercept -0.019413 is probably statistically insignificant in this case. To verify that you have to look at *t*-statistics for example.

On this [page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/250) you can find nice course with visualizations about simple linear regression and other statistical methods answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

From the parameters slope and intercept, you cannot conclude if the line is a good fit. The correlation coefficient says that they depend highly and that a straight line could fit your model. However, from the p-values for the slope and intercept, you can conclude if your fit is good. If they are small (say below 0.05) you can conclude that the fit is pretty good.